# apply porters stemmer to a Pandas column for each word

Tags: python, pandas, porter-stemmer

i have a pandas dataframe called 'data_stem' and there is a column named 'TWEET_SENT_1' which have strings like below (50 rows)

TWEET_SENT_1

the mack daddy of kiss cross

i liked that video body party

i want to apply porters stemmer in to 'TWEET_SENT_1' column (for all words of a row)
i tried below code and it gives an error . could you please help me to overcome this

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer, WordNetLemmatizer
porter_stemmer = PorterStemmer()
data_stem[' TWEET_SENT_1 '] = data_stem[' TWEET_SENT_1 '].apply(lambda x: [porter_stemmer.stem(y) for y in x])
```

below is the error

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-412-c16b1beddfb5> in <module>()
      1 from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer, WordNetLemmatizer
      2 porter_stemmer = PorterStemmer()
----> 3 data_stem[' TWEET_SENT_1 '] = data_stem[' TWEET_SENT_1 '].apply(lambda x: [porter_stemmer.stem(y) for y in x])

C:\Users\SampathR\Anaconda2\envs\dato-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2058             values = lib.map_infer(values, lib.Timestamp)
   2059 
-> 2060         mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2061         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
   2062             from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

pandas\src\inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:58435)()

<ipython-input-412-c16b1beddfb5> in <lambda>(x)
      1 from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer, WordNetLemmatizer
      2 porter_stemmer = PorterStemmer()
----> 3 data_stem[' TWEET_SENT_1 '] = data_stem[' TWEET_SENT_1 '].apply(lambda x: [porter_stemmer.stem(y) for y in x])

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Do you have any `None`s in `data_stem[' TWEET_SENT_1 ']`? Are there indeed spaces around TWEET_SENT_1?

Comment: @DYZ thanks very much. there's no any none in data_stem[' TWEET_SENT_1 ']. yes there are spaces between TWEET_SENT_1. when i execute `porter_stemmer.stem(data_stem.iloc[1,2])` it works. but i want apply it to each words and all rows of the column

Comment: You need to tokenize before applying the way you are. The way you do porter_stemmer.stem(y) in a list comprehension. It will do letter by letter and not word by word which is what you want.

Comment: @Satyadev . following code gives the expected output for one row                  `porter_stemmer.stem(data_stem.iloc[1,2])`                                                           `u' that damn body party song is stuck in my head '  is there any way to do without tokenize as above?  thanks very much for your reply

Comment: From what you have mentioned- TWEET SENT 1 
x = "the mack daddy of kiss cross" Can you try [porter_stemmer.stem(y) for y in x] and tell me if you get the desired output?

Comment: @Satyadev yes , 1st row of data_stem relevant to TWEET SENT column is "the mack daddy of kiss cross" , previous message output for for another table

Comment: Then you are stemming on each letter , list comprehension of a string will always give letters. Please try what i have typed in the above comment on an ipython shell and see the output for yourself. While your apply function of pandas applies row by row , the list comprehension is wrong. You need to tokenize first and then stem. Also the none type error is most likely because of a None value in that column. Can you try this - sum(df['TWEET_SENT_1].isnull()) and print the output of it here ?

Comment: sum(df['TWEET_SENT_1].isnull())  gives as 50 (that is total number of rows. can you suggest me the code to run [porter_stemmer.stem(y) for y in x] for "the mack daddy of kiss cross"  i'm a novice to python :)

Comment: @Satyadev there was a error in a previous code and hence TWEET SENT column converted to None. now previous functions works. but it gives characters instead of words. is there any work around which i can stemmer string considering words

Comment: Yes , a simple tokenizer first and then do the stemming. I am posting a solution for this , feel free to continue this there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Applying three different operations to the series with millions of rows is very expensive operation. Instead, apply all at once:

```
def stem_sentences(sentence):
    tokens = sentence.split()
    stemmed_tokens = [porter_stemmer.stem(token) for token in tokens]
    return ' '.join(stemmed_tokens)

data_stem['TWEET_SENT_1'] = data_stem['TWEET_SENT_1'].apply(stem_sentences)
```

(Note: This is just a modified version of the accepted answer)

Answer (score 7):

What you need to do first is tokenize your sentences. Tokenize means splitting a sentence into words based on the kind of delimiters you have so that you avoid things like punctuations which sometimes are not really required. This depends on the use case though. In sequence modeling where you are trying to predict the next sequence, a comma matters but when you are trying to get pos tags for words just for analysis , it might not.Anyhow, here is how to do the tokenization.

```
data_stem['TWEET_TOKENIZED']=data_stem['TWEET_SENT_1'].apply(lambda x : filter(None,x.split(" ")))
```

Apply your stemmer to the above tokenized column as follows:

```
data_stem['Tweet_stemmed']=data_stem['TWEET_TOKENIZED'].apply(lambda x : [porter_stemmer.stem(y) for y in x])
```

Update : Adding concatenation functionality

To get back the tweet into sentence format, do the following:

```
data_stem['tweet_stemmed_sentence']=data_stem['Tweet_stemmed'].apply(lambda x : " ".join(x))
```

Comment: Great this works like a charm. small request, can i get the output as same as original string. ex: original text was 'the mack daddy of kiss cross' and Tweet_stemmed result is [the, mack, daddy, of, kiss, cross] , can i convert this again in to original format(not to the orginal words) without comma(,) and square brackets

Comment: Can you paste some sample output here? Also , don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your question.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: thanks very very much. you saved me :). i accepted the answer